# Not looping through JSON Object Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, api

Im currently trying to make my own crypto watchlist. Im using the CoinRankingAPI (https://developers.coinranking.com/api/documentation/coins). Im trying to loop through the coin data in order to retrieve the price, but I get an error stating that the object im trying to iterate over isn't irritable. Source code will be below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
const key = 'XXXX';

const url = 'https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?' + key;


//Loads Stats Data
function loadPrices() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var coins = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      // get 'data' key inside response
      var price = coins.data;

      // loop all the teams
      for (var coin of price) {
          // print full name and abbreivation
          document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML += "<br />" + coin["price"] ;
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: If it's not iterable then it's not an array.  So what is it?  When you debug, what value do you observe in `price`?  What value do you expect it to have?  Why?

Comment: Can you post the value of `this.responseText`?

Comment: I believe you want ```coins.data.coins``` according to the api docs

Comment: Please provide an extract of the data you're getting from the external API so that readers of your question don't have to needlessly repeat research you have already done and/or potentially sign up to random websites.  Since you are asking for help debugging, you need to provide an [mre]

Comment: So what are you trying to loop over? `console.log(price)` Never hurts to debug.

Comment: FYI: Don't use `.getElementById()` for the same element in a loop. Just get it once prior to the loop and then use that reference instead of searching the DOM for it on every loop iteration. Also, don't use `.innerHTML` in a loop either as it causes the DOM to be reparsed upon each iteration. Instead, build up a string of HTML with the loop and after the loop is done, set that as the `.innerHTML`, which will only rebuild the DOM one time.

Comment: As to your specific question, just log what you are getting back as the `responseText` and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the expected response from the provided link, it returns the coins as an object, that contains `data` value, which in turn contains the `coins`. You also have an issue in how you build your request and handling the event. So, in order to iterate over the coins try this code:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    const req = e.target;

    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(req.response);

        // get 'data' key inside response
        const coins = response.data.coins;

        for (let coin of coins) {
            document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML += "<br />" + coin["price"] ;
        }
    }
}
```

But at the same time, you can use fetch API and `async`/`await` which will simplify your code. So, let me provide a better/optimized version of your code:

```
const key = 'XXXX';
const url = 'https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?' + key;

//Loads Stats Data
async function loadPrices() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    const coins = (await response.json()).data.coins;

    const helloElm = document.getElementById("hello");


    // loop all the teams
    let output = '';
    for (var coin of coins) {
        // print full name and abbreivation
        output += "<br />" + coin["price"] ;
    }
    helloElm.innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` in a loop as it causes the DOM to be reparsed upon each iteration. Instead, build up a string of HTML with the loop and after the loop is done, set that as the `.innerHTML`, which will only rebuild the DOM one time.